# $\dfrac{\sin \pi (2M+1) u}{\sin \pi u} = \sum^M_{k=-M} e^{-2\pi iku}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't proof the following identity [From page 5 of the book "The Riemann Zeta-Function" by A. Karatsuba and S. Voronin] : $$\dfrac{\sin \pi (2M+1) u}{\sin \pi u} = \sum^M_{k=-M} e^{-2\pi iku}.$$ Starting from the r.h.s. I arrive at another term: $$\sum^M_{k=-M} e^{-2\pi iku} = e^{2\pi iu} \times \Big( \dfrac{1-e^{2\pi iMu}}{1-e^{2\pi iu}} \Big) + 1 + e^{-2\pi iu} \times \Big( \dfrac{1-e^{-2\pi iMu}}{1-e^{-2\pi iu}} \Big) = \dfrac {2-e^{2\pi i(M+1)u}-e^{-2\pi i(M+1)u}}{2-e^{2\pi iu}-e^{-2\pi iu}} =  \Big( \dfrac{\sin \pi (M+1) u}{\sin \pi u} \Big)^2  \ne? \dfrac{\sin \pi (2M+1) u}{\sin \pi u}.$$

Comment: check the numerator of you second equality :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is a geometric sum & is easy enough to calculte. Let $ x =e^{2 \pi i u}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=-M}^{M} x^k= \frac{x^{-M}-x^{M+1}}{1-x} = \frac{x^{M+\frac{1}{2}}-x^{-M-\frac{1}{2}}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use $e^{i \pi u}-e^{-i \pi u}=2 \sin( \pi u)$.

Answer (score 1):

A proof by induction is also possible. In the base case $M=0$, the sum collapses to $\dfrac{\sin \pi u}{\sin \pi u}=\sum_{k=0}e^{-2\pi i k u}=1$ which is true. Moreover, if it is true for some $M=n$ then for $M=n+1$ we have

\begin{align}
\sum^{n+1}_{k=-n-1} e^{-2\pi iku}
&=e^{2\pi i(n+1)u}+e^{-2\pi i(n+1)u}+\sum^{n}_{k=-n}e^{-2\pi iku}\\
&=2\cos [2\pi(n+1)u]+\frac{\sin((2n+1)\pi u}{\sin \pi u}.\\
\end{align}
But $2\cos [2\pi(n+1)]\sin \pi u=\sin((2n+3)\pi u)-\sin((2n+1)\pi u)$ follows from a product-to-sum identity; from this it follows that the equality holds for $M=n+1$ and therefore we conclude that it's true for all $M$ by induction.